# Store hashtable in a session

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, session, hashtable

How can I store HashTable collection to a Session variable in .NET. Unfortunately I'm not able to store HashTable nor Dictionary.

Please help me in this.

Comment: Please explain why you can't do that, then we might be able to help. What did you try, what problems did you get?

Comment: Please define why you are "not able to store Hashtable or Dictionary" since they are perfectly fine objects to store in a `Session` variable.

Comment: What kind of objects are  you storing in these dictionaries / hashtables? Are they serializable? And what kind of session state provider are you using (in proc, state server...etc.?).

Comment: Its just string data. I dont know why its not getting stored.. you can see my comment down with the code.... While im assigning the entire data is there in the Hashtable Object.. but later when i call it im not getting it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer.. There was no problem with the code ie new keyword. In the above step after storing to Session i was clearing the HashTable items.

```
         Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
         if(condition){

        ht.Add("id", 1);
        ht.Add("name", "ram");
        Session["hashtab"] = ht;  
        }

        ht.Clear();
```

this ht.Clear() was the problem. I removed it and have no issue with it.
It  was like this. when i removed that code its working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why can't you able to store hashtable into session and get it back from session since it is as simple as storing table or any object in session.
If i understood your problem correctly I can provide solution as below.

Do like this in the page where you want to store the hashtable into session.

```
 Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
            ht.Add("id", 1);
            ht.Add("name", "ram");
            Session["hashtab"] = ht;
```

and get the hashtable in other page as below.

Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        ht =(Hashtable)Session["hashtab"];

Comment: When you get the hashtable, skip the new; it points it to newly created hashtable, then right away you point it to the one in the session. So the first allocation is wasted time & memory to garbage collect later. Will still work, with no real ill in this case, but if you do this in a tight loop it could cause non-negligible waste of time and memory.